# How to get client IP address from inside a Azure Kubernetes with a ClusterIP service

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I having a WebAPI Application deployed in Kubernetes and when we are accessing the API, we need to log the system IP from where the application gets accessed. In simple, I need to get the Client IP / System IP from where the API gets invoked. In order to get the IP Address, I am using

```
HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString()
```

but it is always returning the Node IP Address of Kubernetes instead of client IP Address. The Service abstraction / service that are created in Kubernetes is of type "ClusterIP".

Is it possible to get the client IP with a service of type ClusterIP?.

Comment: I'm not clear what do you mean the "client IP"?

Comment: The Client IP is the System IP from  where the application is accessed. We are having an .NET Application deployed in Azure Kubernetes. When we are access the application, we need to log the system IP from where the application gets accessed. In order to get the Client IP, I am using below code HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString(). but this code always returning the Kubernetes node IP Address. hope it is clear now

Comment: @user2003780, please edit the question an put all necessary information there.

Comment: @user2003780 https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/) given by [Maciek Sawicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201306/maciek-sawicki), services of type ClusterIP, are accessible from within a cluster and hence services of type ClusterIP are not accessible outside the cluster. So the traffic to such services, come from either nodes or through other pods.

However if you want to log the IP address of the client, change the service type to NodePort or load balancer and then add `service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy` to the value `Local` as given in the above link.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion malathi.  We are having more than one application and each application is deployed in separate cluster. Will there be any impact by changing the service type to load balancer?

Comment: What do you mean by different clusters? If you are not using load balancers right now, how are you accessing the services now?

Comment: I have create a independent application and deployed in Kubernetes. As of now, I have created a service with type ClusterIP.

Comment: I hope your traffic comes from external world and not within kubernetes cluster. Load balancer is the suggested way to handle the scenario. In fact load balancer helps with things like load balancing, managing pod IPs dynamically.